# How to show point on the google map with java script in asp.net page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I'm write this code for show get point from asp button and show the point on the map:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
   <script>
       var myCenter;
       var center;
       var isButtonClick = false;
       function initialize(x,y) {

           var mapProp = {
               center: new google.maps.LatLng(x,y),

               zoom: 5,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
           };
           myCenter: center;
           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                   position: new google.maps.LatLng(testArray[0], testArray[1]),
                   animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
               });
               marker.setMap(map);
               alert("0=" + testArray[0]);
               alert("1=" + testArray[1]);


       }
       google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () { if (!isButtonClick) initialize(0, 0) });
    </script>
```

and write this code into asp button click event for send value to java script function:

```
List < string > tempString = new List < string > ();
tempString.Add("45.123321");
tempString.Add("35.567890");

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<script>");
sb.Append("var testArray = new Array;");
foreach(string str in tempString) {
    sb.Append("testArray.push('" + str + "');");
}
sb.Append("</script>");

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "TestArrayScript", sb.ToString());
```

but point not show to me!,how can i solve that?

Comment: Your javascript is working fine using constants, did the alert work for testArray[0] and testArray[1]?

Answer (score 0):

Couple suggestions for the second half of the code (since the first half, when tested, returned a desired result), try to print out sb, see if it is indeed the script that you wanted to append.

I don't quite understand your logic in setting `var isButtonClick = false;` and then passing in `function () { if (!isButtonClick) initialize(0, 0) });` Maybe you can clear that up.

Maybe you need to make sure that function initialize runs after the sb is added to the .

Hope this gives you some new ideas, or narrow down where to pinpoint your bug at least. Cheers!!